# How to use Unity UNet networking to call a single player?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I have client/server program, the client calls the server using [command], then I want server to call back just that one client with some data, or call some function on that one player without sending/calling to all other clients.

Does anybody know how to do it, and can you please show an example. I saw a function called SendToClientOfPlayer, but I cant find any example of how to use it, I dont even know if this is the right function to use.

Answer (score 0):

u can use clientRPC

for example

`[ClientRpc]
void RpcSendToClientOfPlayer(){
//do work
}`

whenever u call it, it'll broadcast this function to all the clients

PS: make sure u have Rpc as prefix to the function